# Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

This is my script:

```
            if(entfernung2<=1 && drive=="AUT"){
                dauer = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
                dauer.getDistanceMatrix({
                origins: ["48.142362,11.549859"],
                destinations: ["48.2,11.4"],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                })
            dauer1=dauer.rows.elements.duration.text;
            };
```

if i log dauer1 following errors are shown:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Whats wrong? :/

EDIT:

```
            if(entfernung2<=1 && drive=="AUT"){
                dauer = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            dauer.getDistanceMatrix(
            {
              origins: ["48.142362,11.549859"],
              destinations: ['"'+data.position.latitude+','+data.position.longitude+'"'],
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
              unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
            }, setDauer1);

            function setDauer1(response, status) {
              dauer1 = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value;
              console.log(dauer1);
            }};
```

Comment: `dauer.rows` is an array, which doesn't have an `elements` property. But the array's objects do (e.g. `dauer.rows[0].elements.duration.text`)

Comment: Now i get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: The Json looks like this: 
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "San Francisco, Californie, États-Unis" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Vancouver, BC, Canada" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1 709 km",
                  "value" : 1709199
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 jours 19 heures",
                  "value" : 327594
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getDistanceMatrix` is asynchronous, so `dauer1` is defined before `dauer` gets updated. By looking at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix?hl=fr#distance_matrix_requests), you need a callback:

```
dauer.getDistanceMatrix(
{
  origins: ["48.142362,11.549859"],
  destinations: ["48.2,11.4"],
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
}, setDauer1);

function setDauer1(response, status) {
  dauer1 = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
  // your code continues here
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) ... Now i get the Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined

and sometimes Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Comment: if(entfernung2<=1 && drive=="AUT"){
                    dauer = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
                dauer.getDistanceMatrix(
                {
                  origins: ["48.142362,11.549859"],
                  destinations: ["48.2,11.4"],
                  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
                  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
                }, setDauer1);

                function setDauer1(response, status) {
                  dauer1 = response[0].rows.elements.duration.text;
                }};

Comment: @SebastianLzlem I just updated that line. `elements` is also an array, so if you want the first element, add `[0]`. Note that this piece of code doesn't check if there is actually a result.

Comment: @SebastianLzlem Works for me: [**JS Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yy1jovu4/). Do a `console.log(dauer1)` instead of an `alert`, what do you get in your console (_F12_)?

Comment: So finally it got this code (EDIT above).. I get the Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: @SebastianLzlem `destinations: [+'"'` should be `destinations: ['"'`.

Comment: @SebastianLzlem Ok, then are you certain that `data.position.latitude` and longitude are correctly defined? What happens if you keep your code as it is and just replace it with fake values like `"48.2,11.4"`? If it works, that's your problem. If not, I'm afraid I won't be of much help without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: mhm .. okay ... the error is gone now ... but dauer1 is still undefined :/ Can i send you the complete code?

Comment: @SebastianLzlem Weird because if I copy/paste your code in [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yy1jovu4/2/) it works. Oh, and I did not pay attention, when you do `destinations: ['"'`, you're creating a String with wrapping quotes, but the string should not have quotes in it. Remove `'"'` on each side (see JS Fiddle)

Comment: I think its because dauer1 is not known outside the function?

Heres the complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/kv9n9fuu/

Comment: Did you notice my comment `// Your code continues here` ? If you have any code outside that uses `dauer1`, it should be triggered from `setDauer1()`, because if not, it won't be defined yet (even if it is written after).

Comment: Ok so if i want to use dauer1 outside i have to write something like dauer2=dauer1; inside the setDauer1 and then use dauer2?

Comment: @SebastianLzlem Ok, I looked at your code. That's what I thought, you are doing `console.log(dauer1)` outside of the `setDauer1()` function. The problem? That console.log is executed before `setDauer1()` is, because, as I told you, `getDistanceMatrix()` is asynchronous. You need to either put the rest of the code inside `setDauer1()`, OR wrap it in a function like `function keepGoing(){console.log(dauer1);}`, and call that function inside `setDauer1()`. If that is not clear enough for you, I encourage you to learn about asynchronous functions, like ajax, and callbacks.